# Why do I keep receiving close votes for answerable questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I received a close vote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105277/how-to-use-enumwindows-with-a-com-wrapper-in-vbscript), but it is not a bad question or an off topic one and is a verifiable example. It also has a reproducible problem.

Please can you show me what's wrong with this question, so I can keep away from doing it again?

Comment: It's only **one** close vote, it doesn't mean that it's gonna get closed

Comment: I wouldnt concern myself too much with it.. You even have an upvote..

Comment: But I think this question seems boring to read and is too long.

Comment: You received a **too broad** close vote, cast by an experienced community member. I don't know enough about the subject matter to make any judgement calls on the applicability of the vote. It is also *just one vote*.

Comment: `But I think this question seems boring to read and is too long` If you feel that way, you can always try to make it shorter and more on point. Never a mistake

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for important information. :-)

Comment: Your question *does* come over as rather open-ended; *and will VBScript support using it?*, *I read ... but I can't understand how to use it with EnumWindows's callback EnumWindowsProc. Please help me more on this.* are definite trigger sentences for me.

Comment: Definite trigger sentences mean?

Comment: Note that *"answerable"* is a very minimal requirement; it's necessary, but not sufficient, for a good SO question.

Comment: It's not you, but the question.

Comment: 'it is not a bad question or an off topic one' well, when it comes to votes, you don't get to determine that:)   Just that claim comes across as bad, and could get downvotes on its own.

Comment: @GTAVLover "Definite trigger sentences mean?" It means strong indications that there's something wrong.  Another term here would be a "red flag".  They make the query very open ended and vague, which is likely to make it Too Broad.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, then how should I ask it instead? Like "Does VBScript support it?" or how else?

Comment: @GTAVLover Asking if VBScript supports it now is certainly a much more answerable question than asking people to speculate on whether it will or won't do so in the future.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for great information! :-}

Comment: Perhaps someone thought you were asking multiple questions?

Comment: @BSMP I also thought, but I like to know if there is a question limit in SO that a user can ask for a day or for a week etc.?

Comment: Oh, I meant that they may have thought you had multiple questions in that one question post, not that you were asking too many in general. (I think there is rate-limiting on the number of questions one can post but I forget the specifics.)

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for sharing ;-)